# How to know if MS Access data is modified?

Tags: java, ms-access, jackcess

I pretend to add records to a MS Database from Java. I able to do it using Jackess but for any reason, the software using this database is not seeing the data until:
1 close and reopen the software, or
2 open the database with MS Access and close it regardless modify the data

this software is a POS, When I enter records from any of the terminals, these are visible from the other, When I enter records from MS Access, these are visible from any terminal, I dont have to close and reopen the software. However if I enter records from my Java app is not visible automatically.

Is there any flag in a .mdb file to notify data is changed?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like your Java application _Begin_ a transaction which it never _Commit_.

Comment: I think the share functions within jackccess is not implemented. No manage of .ldb files so the other apps dont detect the modifications and I think it is dangerous write using jackccess in a multi user environment...

Comment: Control of the ldb file only determines if you can open the database file shared. If not, it will and must be opened exclusively - which requires that no other process has opened the database, neither shared nor exclusively.

Comment: ok, but how it is checked if data is modified?

Comment: Can't tell. I know nothing about Java, nor Jacksess.

Answer (score 1):

> I think it is dangerous write using jackccess in a multi user environment

It is. Jackcess should not be used to write to an Access database file when you have multiple concurrent users.

Your POS system and Access itself both use the Access Database Engine to manage concurrent users. Even though each machine runs it own copy of the Access Database Engine, those copies work co-operatively to keep track of changes to the database file.

On the other hand, Jackcess does not use the Access Database Engine at all; it writes directly to the Access database file. It has no practical way of knowing what other processes may have done to the file, and it has no practical way of telling those other processes that it has changed the file.

Conclusion: If your environment has multiple concurrent users, do not use Jackcess to update the database.